# Where to get the new string after running `sub` in awk

Tags: awk

From The Awk Programming Language

> The function  `sub ( r, s , t )`  first finds  the leftmost longest 
>   substring  matched  by  the  regular expression  `r`  in  the  target 
>   string  `t`;  it  then replaces  the substring by  the substitution
>   string `s`.
>
> The  function `sub(r,s)` is a synonym for  `sub(r,s,$0)`.
>
> In  `sub ( /ana/, "anda" , "banana" )`, for  example,  `banana` is 
>   replaced with `bandada`.

After running `sub ( r, s , t )`, how can I get the new string?
For example, in `sub ( /ana/, "anda" , "banana" )`, how can I get the new string `bandada`?

> The  sub function  returns  the  number  of substitutions  made.

Is the return of `sub` either 0 or 1? Is it correct that it can't be more than one, because `sub` only find the first match and replace it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From the GNU awk manual [9.1.3 String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

> ... the third argument to `sub()` must be a variable, field, or array
>   element. Some versions of awk allow the third argument to be an
>   expression that is not an lvalue. In such a case, `sub()` still searches
>   for the pattern and returns zero or one, but the result of the
>   substitution (if any) is thrown away because there is no place to put
>   it. Such versions of awk accept expressions like the following:
>
> `sub(/USA/, "United States", "the USA and Canada")`
>
> For historical
>   compatibility, gawk accepts such erroneous code. However, using any
>   other nonchangeable object as the third parameter causes a fatal error
>   and your program will not run.

So, the answer is to use a variable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{t = "banana"; sub(/ana/,"anda",t); print t}'
bandana
```